# unable to see nested ul in html

Tags: html, css

I want to generate nested un-ordered list just like :
 `

- List item one
- List item two with subitems:

  - Subitem 1
  - Subitem 2
- Final list item

my html code is :

```
<nav id="nav">
<ul>
<li>List item one</li>
<li>List item two with subitems:
    <ul>
        <li>Subitem 1</li>
        <li>Subitem 2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Final list item</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

but I only get out put as :

- List item one
- List item two with subitems:
- Final list item

not the nested ul list my CSS is :

```
#nav
{
}

    #nav > ul > li > ul
    {
        display: none;
    }

    #nav ul
    {
        margin: 0;
    }

    #nav li
    {
        border-top: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.075);
        padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0;
    }

    #nav li:first-child
    {
        border: 0;
        box-shadow: none;
        padding-top: 0;
    }

    #nav li:last-child
    {
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }

    #nav li a
    {
        display: block;
        padding: 0.4em 1em 0.4em 1em;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: 0.4em;
        outline: 0;
        -moz-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out, color .25s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out, color .25s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out, color .25s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out, color .25s ease-in-out;
        transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out, color .25s ease-in-out;
    }

    #nav li.current_page_item a
    {
        background-color: #272E39 !important;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.15) !important;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.05), inset 0 0 0.25em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #fff;
    }

    #nav li:hover a
    {
        background-color: rgba(200,225,255,0.1);
        color: #fff;
    }
```

Please can any one help me to point out where am I missing some thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, without any css it will print same as you want.
You don't need to give css.

You can add css for some formatting.

And you have gave, `display:none;`, it will not print it.

Have you referred any css documentation ?

Look [this](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/sub_master.htm)  demo.

So it will better if you understand all tag first with it's property then go for design otherwise you are always get this type of small but silly problem.

And why have you use `a` in css ? I don't understand.

Look your [code working](http://jsfiddle.net/7g49h/) by removing, `display:none;`

Comment: OK, thanks for your Answer, but now an other issue raises which is if I have more then one inner list item it is shown as a outer list item. How can I fix that??

Comment: Not jsfiddle.net/7g49h/1 works fine, but my html does not :-(

Comment: Means ? what exactly you want ? will you tell me ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, your CSS specifically tells not to display it :

```
#nav > ul > li > ul
{
    display: none;
}
```

So your problem is a feature, not a bug...

Comment: OK, thanks for your Answer, but now an other issue raises which is if I have more then one inner list item it is shown as a outer list item. How can I fix that?

Comment: basically your problem is your CSS and you could probably fix anything just by using a proper CSS. But it would be easier to get the problem through a jsFiddle within a new question cause this is about a different problem than your original question.